# How to Identify Fields from Field Collection?

Tags: entities

I have a Content Type, which has field collection and I need to load the fields present inside the field collection, Any idea on how to do this?

**Very Important Note:** There is no content created for this Content Type as yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
$entity_type = 'field_collection_item';
$bundle_name = 'field_profile_address';

$info = field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle_name);

// $info at this point is an array of fields attached to the queried bundle.
```

From your last 2 questions I think you'd be very interested in the [Field Info API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/group/field_info/7).